# From my Rails form, I'm getting a 404 Error. Anyone know how to properly set up this AJAX form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
= form_tag :url => job_path(@job.id), :method => :post, :remote => true, :id => @job.id, do
        = submit_tag 'Save', :class => 'confirm-time'
```

This is how I instantiate it. I'm just kinda throwing a bunch of params in there. Most of which are probably not necessary.

My jQuery Call :

```
    $(".confirm-time").live("click", function(){
      $.post($(this).parents('form').attr('action'), function(){} );
      return false;
    });
```

And my response is :

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/jobs/171"
```

But this is definately a route, because it works otherwise. Anyone know what I might be missing?

My Routes :

```
resources :jobs
```

There's a lot of associated jobs to this -- that to jobs. But I figured this would suffice because this is a simple post to the `def udpate`

My Logs  :

```
Started POST "/jobs/171?method=post&remote=true&url=%2Fjobs%2F171" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-03 14:09:23 -0400
  SQL (0.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.9ms)  SHOW TABLES
[Barista] Compiling all scripts for barista
[Barista] Compiling all coffeescripts
[E20::Ops::Middleware::TransactionIdMiddleware] Transaction ID: e8c81711-3d8b-438e-b6d2-ba77f1bda40d

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/jobs/171"):


Rendered /Users/elephanttrip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@shasta/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

Comment: There's no need for the controller. It doesn't even reach `def update`.

Comment: can you paste logs from the server. the request log of mongrel, thin or whatever you are using.

Comment: You have an obvious syntax error in your code, there shouldn't be a comma before `do` for `form_tag`.

Answer (score 1):

The URL your app is hitting is completely wrong, this should have been your first clue that you're not using the `form_tag` helper correctly:

```
/jobs/171?method=post&remote=true&url=%2Fjobs%2F171
```

As you can see, the entire options hash is being used as the URL parameter, because the first argument to `form_tag` is the URL.

It should look like this:

```
form_tag job_path(@job.id), :method => :post, :remote => true, :id => @job.id do
```

You're also misusing the `*_path` helpers; You should use `job_path(@job)` or just pass in the Job object itself:

```
form_tag @job, :method => :post, :remote => true, :id => @job.id do
```

You're also using the wrong method. POST is for creating new objects, and your form is updating an existing object which is a PUT request. You'll either want to use `:method => :put` or (preferably) drop `form_tag` all together and use `form_for @job`, which will figure out everything for you based on the object you pass it:

```
form_for @job, :remote => true do |form|
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me clean that up. But still getting a route error on this one.

Comment: You probably don't need `:method => :post`, `form_tag` will figure out the correct method based on the state of `@job`. It almost certainly should be a `:put` request anyways, which is probably why no route is matching.

Comment: I stand corrected, if you want to use `form_tag` then you'll need to use `:method => :put`. The better solution is just to use `form_for`.

Comment: Dang. Tried everything. Must be something else. I'll keep you posted. Thanks so much for all your help.